# John Wallis's geometric representation of a complex number

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

I'm new to the forum but I have seen a lot of great discussions and answers here before so hopefully someone could explain this to me.

In the work of John Wallis, "A treatise of algebra", he makes perhaps the first geometric representation of the complex number. He does so by comparing two cases, where he utilizes the Pythagorean theorem of triangles to solve for side AB (As the included image).

[image]

It is in the second case that he draw points B such that PB<PC, which makes for a negative square (imaginary number) if the formula remains the same as in the first case. What I don't understand, is why he applies the same formula for AB as he did in the first case when that formula doesn't work in the second case for AB? It seems almost irrelevant to me, but I am obviously not seeing something.

He goes through this for both cases in the following link, end of page 5 to 7, which is from the [book](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/2001/2001.10400.pdf).

UPDATE:

Reading this and the previous section in the book, which I included in the link, Wallis's starts with his interpretation of negative numbers and that he only sees it as going backwards on the number line, compared to positive numbers going forward. For example, the difference is the same for (85-20) and (20-85), but they go in opposite directions on the number line. With case 1 as an example, he then shows how a negative root is still a real root (since B can be two points, + or - the squared root in the equation).

He then applies this interpretation when using the Pythagorean theorem. Instead of subtracting either the opposite² or adjacent² from the hypotenuse², he subtracts the hypotenuse² from one of them.

So now what is left for him to do, is to present a case where the square is negative. And I think this is what he does in case 2: he shows that the only way **for BC to become a negative square, is when PB < PC in the formula, and that this implies that B have to leave the Aa line**. Meaning, according to his reasoning, that to geometrically visualize a complex number it requires a 2-dimensional plain.

By using this interpretation and treating the negative square as a imaginary number, it makes sense that the same formula can be used in case 2 as in case 1. He also shows an example in which adding the double value of AB (since there can be two B's) will result in the same double AC (2AC) in both cases, in other words the same real solution even when incorporating the imaginary number.

Comment: Welcome!!! So glad to have you here. You actually copy paste image into the subject body.

Comment: Thanks, actually I tried to but it said that I needed more reputation points or something like that and that in the meantime it would be linked? @Aplateofmomos

Comment: If you think about it PBC is on a circle but I am not sure if that helps

Comment: Well he actually use a circle in his own drawing having the diameter PC in the second case, I think mainly because that way one can show that PBC has a right angle in vertex B (due to Thales' theorem), which is necessary to produce the negative square. @Aplateofmomos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that Wallis is asserting that the formula is correct in the second case as well if you correctly interpret the square root geometrically in the complex plane he may be inventing. (I would have to see much more of the context to work out the details.)

For more history check out [Caspar Wessel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspar_Wessel).

Comment: Hmmm, Ethan. If Wallis’s trick is at all usable, that would give him great priority over Wessel…

Comment: Yes I've read some about Wessel as well. Though the complex number seem to have been accepted even before him since Euler, De Moivre and others derived trigonometric identities prior to his work.  @Lubin

Comment: Thanks, I think you are totally right. If I deal with the negative square as the imaginary number it is, the formula is correct. It seems so obvious now. This is what he means when he then adds the double values of AB, it will equal the same 2AC in both cases.